Cisco Anyconnect: Illegal Packet
We use Cisco Anyconnect at my university to use its VPN, but since it is an old server, it doesn't support recent SSL protocols. Whenever I tried to connect using my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I received the error:

A packet with illegal or unsupported version was received.

How can I solve this?

Hi! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thanks for participating! I appreciate your willingness to help the community by providing a solution to a problem you faced that could help others as well, but Ask Ubuntu (as all Stack Exchange sites), unlike a forum, has a rather strict question-answer(s) format: a question must clearly present the issue and an answer must provide (or intend to) an solution to that. Since you included the solution in the question, I edited and moved it out of it and posted it as a Community Wiki (CW) answer. This way I won't get any points from it.

If you wish to post the answer yourself, please feel free to do so and I will remove the CW. Thank you again for trying to be helpful! :)


After some back and forth with the support team from my university,
they provided a solution:

Edit the file /etc/gnutls/config:
[overrides]
default-priority-string = NORMAL
#disabled-version = tls1.0
#disabled-version = tls1.1
#disabled-version = dtls0.9
#disabled-version = dtls1.0


Connect to the VPN via terminal using:
openconnect URL -u USER


After that, you can use the GUI connection.


I hope this helps someone who is having the same problem.

Answer moved here from OP's question.
